# Application of Complex Logarithm and Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I encountered this problem in a textbook, and I'm really having trouble solving it. Here it goes:

Let $0<r<R$ and $f: \overline{A_{r,R}} \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and holomorphic in the interior. For $s \in (r,R)$ let $\theta = \frac{\log(R)-\log(s)}{\log(R)-\log(r)}$. How can I show that

\begin{align*}
\max_{C_s}|f| \leq \max_{C_r}|f|^\theta\max_{C_R}|f|^{1-\theta}
\end{align*}
The hint that is given is that I should first show that the function $\alpha \log|z| + \log|f(z)|$ is harmonic with $\alpha$ chosen carefully. I'm really confused on how to get started. I see why the maximum modulus principle is relevant, but I can't see how to apply it. I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Hint: for any $\alpha$, the maximum $M(\alpha)$ of the function $\alpha\log{|z|} + \log{|f(z)|}$ is reached on the border of the corona. So, can you give an explicit value of $M(\alpha)$ in terms of useful quantities from the RHS?

Comment: sorry i'm still a bit confused! Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The maximum $M_1(\alpha)$ of $\alpha\log{|z|}+\log{|f(z)|}$ on $C_r$ is $\alpha\log{r}+\max_{C_r}\log{|f|}$. The maximum $M_2(\alpha)$ of the same function on $C_R$ is $\alpha\log{R}+\max_{C_R}\log{|f|}$. Now, for any $z \in C_s$, you thus have $\alpha\log{s}+\log{|f(z)|} \leq \max(M_1(\alpha),M_2(\alpha))$. So what can you say about the minimum value over all $\alpha$ of $\max(M_1(\alpha),M_2(\alpha))-\alpha\log{s}$?